# Why do ffmpeg developers use "runtime if" with macrofied condition?

Tags: c, ffmpeg, c-preprocessor

I'm looking to FFmpeg source code and I find it weird to use weird code like this:

```c
#define MACRO 0
void func(void)
{
    if (MACRO) 
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to use "if" instead of "#if ... #endif" when dealing with macros?

Some examples of this in ffmpeg repo

- [GitHub - libavcodec/me_cmp.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavcodec/me_cmp.c#L1064-L1073)
- [GitHub - libavcodec/h264pred.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavcodec/h264pred.c#L591-L600)
- [GitHub - libavcodec/h264qpel.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavcodec/h264qpel.c#L99-L110)
- [GitHub - libavcodec/h264chroma.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavcodec/h264chroma.c#L49-L60)
- [GitHub - libavcodec/h264dsp.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavcodec/h264dsp.c#L155-L160)
- [GitHub - libavcodec/videodsp.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavcodec/videodsp.c#L48-L59)
- [GitHub - libavutil/cpu.c](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bb4e0f6162fa0d5689c12fc8d9fafb1476f6119a/libavutil/cpu.c#L253-L264)

Comment: should produce the same result after optimisation and makes sure that the code inside the `if` block is syntactically valid

Answer (score 0):

> Why ffmpeg developers using "runtime if" with macrofied condition

The reason is when the macro is not a *constant expression*, as in what can be evaluated by `#if`. It may happen that one of the constants depending on architecture is (was) not a constant expression in all possible paths.

```
bool do_we_have_mmx_function() {
    __asm__("magic here");
}
#define HAVE_MMX   do_we_have_mmx_function()
#if HAVE_MMX   // invalid
   if (HAVE_MMX) { // ok
```

Comment: So, it was fixed [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/40e6575aa3eed64cd32bf28c00ae57edc5acb25a). It means there was no that cases in ffmpeg source code before.